# Use svg files using class names

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, frontend

I have downloaded some .svg files from ionicon but i am not able to use them using class name.

```
<my-icon>heart</my-icon>

<my-icon class="heart"></my-icon>
```

Comment: How is it supposed to work ?  Try crosschecking the class names for the icon

Comment: Hi ! What do you expect this piece of html to do ? `<my-icon>` is not a regular html tag, do you mean `<svg>` ?

Comment: just a custom component or tag. Ionic icons have <ion-icon>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to implement icons.

1. Import the css first & use correct class names for the icons, you can set colors later as you wish.
2. Import the css and write custom css for your custom class name

```css
.heart::before {
  content: "\f388";
  display: inline-block;
    font-family: "Ionicons";
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  color: green;
}

.heart-icon {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="heart-icon ion-android-favorite"></span>
<br><br>
<span class="heart"></span>
```

PS. Stack overflow snippet won't work, click on codepen link below to see changes

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/oNwVLeQ)

Ionicons reference for class names: https://ionic.io/ionicons/v2

Or if you still want to use custom downloaded icons you can try setting it in a psuedo element and can change its color using filter property.

```css
.custom_icon::before {
  content: url('https://svgsilh.com/svg/614515.svg');
  max-height: 17px;
  max-width: 13px;
  transform: scale(0.009);
  filter: invert(48%) sepia(79%) saturate(2476%) hue-rotate(86deg) brightness(118%) contrast(119%);
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<span class="custom_icon"></span>
```

Comment: You used 'content: "\f388"; '. Where can i get list of all the icon codes ?

Comment: I mentioned the reference in the answer

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to put not regular tags in html, like: < my-tag >
This can be runned, but in some computers will not work. I'll show:

```css
my-icon::before {
  content: "\f004";
}
my-icon {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<my-icon></my-icon>
```

But because of that, you can use classes to detect the icons.

Then you can use some options, like:

- background-image: url("your-url-icon.svg");
- the svg tag: Your icon code
- and you can use frameworks, like font-awesome!

```css
.framework-icon {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}
.framework-icon::before {
  content: "\f004";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
svg tag: <br><svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="black" />
</svg>
</div>
<div>
frameworks like font-awesome: <div class="framework-icon"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

1.you may need to convert the .svg to .ttf or .woff format to use like a class name. I found this website can accept svg files and gives .ttf or .woff files as output.

**note:** You can adjust styles of svg by this way easly.

https://glyphter.com/

````
    Example: ```<div class='fa fa-icon'></div>```
````

2.you can create a class which will have that svg as a background to `html <tag>`

```
    <style>
     .svg{
       background:url("image/path" )         
       }
     </style>

     <body>
        <div class="svg"></div>
     </body>
```

You can write your own properties for background class